# Параметр релаксации в итерационных методах

Tags: численные-методы

Почему наличие параметра релаксации в итерационном методе решения СЛАУ увеличивает скорость сходимости этого метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорость сходимости SOR определяется спектральным радиусом матрицы итерационного процесса. Чем меньше этот радиус, тем выше скорость сходимости. Соответственно, варьируя `omega` (параметр релаксации), пытаются добиться более-менее минимального значения спектрального радиуса. В некоторых случаях спектральный радиус может уменьшится на порядок. В таких случаях скорость счёта вырастает на то же самый порядок ).

Проблема в том, что спектральный радиус матрицы итерационного процесса ОЧЕНЬ сильно зависит от вида исходной матрицы уравнения. Общей формулы нет. Поэтому тут как повезёт.

Для примера можете почитать статью https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/math-2016-0065/html в которой исследуется спектральный радиус SOR оператора для трёхдиагональных матриц. Такие матрицы возникают при решении систем дифференциальных уравнений разностными методами.